# accessing to value in two dimensional pointer array in c++

Tags: c++, arrays

I want to declare two dimensional  array with variable size.
I wrote the following code but something goes wrong!

```
int **p2DArray;
p2DArray = new int*[target_counter_new];
for (int i = 0; i < target_counter_new; ++i)
    { 
   p2DArray[i] = new int[target_counter_old];
     }


for(int i_oghli=0;i_oghli<target_counter_new;i_oghli++)
    for(int j_oghli=0;j_oghli<target_counter_old;j_oghli++)
    {
         p2DArray[i_oghli][j_oghli]=i_oghli+10;
         cout<<p2DArray[i_oghli][j_oghli];
    }
```

what is problem here ?

Comment: "but something goes wrong!" can you be a little bit more specific?

Comment: yep
values in p2Array  relates to their address not to i_oghli

Comment: Not sure what this means, for me it works as expected: http://cpp.sh/9wvxvp

Comment: What your variables is mean? :-) . ye kem behtar benvis barardar

Comment: Your code works well with c++98,c++11,c++14. No problem found

Comment: these variables relate to Euclidean distance, I summarized them ;-)

Comment: ye it doesnt have any syntax error but it has logical error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

const int target_counter_new = 4;
const int target_counter_old = 4;
int main() {
    int **p2DArray;
    p2DArray = new int*[target_counter_new];
    for (int i = 0; i < target_counter_new; ++i) { 
       p2DArray[i] = new int[target_counter_old];
    }

    for(int i_oghli=0;i_oghli<target_counter_new;i_oghli++) {
        for(int j_oghli=0;j_oghli<target_counter_old;j_oghli++) {
             p2DArray[i_oghli][j_oghli]=i_oghli+10;
             cout<<p2DArray[i_oghli][j_oghli] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    // don't forget to delete the array
    for (int i = 0 ; i < target_counter_new; ++i) {
        delete [] p2DArray[i];
    }
    delete [] p2DArray;
    return 0;
}
```

Check here : [code](http://ideone.com/ZatFSi)
There doesn't appear to be any problem.

Comment: Glad this helped you.